# Replace control characters does not work in table

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word, I am trying to remove the manual line breaks and paragraph codes within a table.
I have created a macro using the built-in feature to try to do this, however, it does not work when the selected text is a table.
The commands work manually, and worked perfectly when recording the macro.  However, they do not work when running the macro.  I have tweaked the code several ways, however, nothing seems to work.

I have repeated the code below as recorded:

```
`Sub TEST()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^l"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "^p"
    .Replacement.Text = " "
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindAsk
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub`
`
```

This seems to fail in one of two ways:
Using the .Wrap = wdFindAsk the first item "^l" is replaced within the selected table, however the second replacement item "^p" is then replaced in the remainder of the document.

Using the .Wrap = wdFindStop eliminates the prompt. the first item "^l" is replaced within the selected table, however the second replacement item "^p" is then replaced in the remainder of the document - but not in the table.

Comment: I ran your code as posted and was not able to reproduce any problem. All manual and paragraph breaks were replaced in selected text, except the paragraph marks immediatly before and after the table.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  It is odd that it works for you.  The way I use it is I select the table, run the macro, however, it seems to continue outside the selected range.  More to investigate...